# Running watir tests on new machine throws " undefined method `chrome' for Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities:Class"

Tags: ruby, selenium-chromedriver, watir

On old machine
`Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome` returns

`#<Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities:0x00007fe9d10e66f0 @capabilities={:browser_name=>“chrome”}>`

On new machine returns

`` NoMethodError: undefined method `chrome' for Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities:Class ``

I have recently gotten a new mac (macos Ventura) and am trying to get all of my tests to run. (tests with watir run on old machine)

After downloading chromedriver and starting a test I get "undefined method 'chrome'" from the watir gem.

I tracked the source of the error to the method `process_capabilities`in `watir-6.19.1/lib/watir/capabilities.rb:93`. The line there is
`caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.send @browser, @options.merge(@w3c_caps)`. `@browser = :chrome, @options = {}` << default setting

I thought it might be a problem with chromedriver but I am able to start it locally and chromedrive is in my PATH.

I tried to start a watir instance in irb but got the same error.

`which chromedriver`
/opt/homebrew/bin/chromedriver

`echo $PATH`
/Users/charlie.alderete/.rbenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

`chromedriver`
Starting ChromeDriver 117.0.5938.88 (be6afae4721209be42944bbcd325665f9f44563b-refs/branch-heads/5938_62@{#9}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.

Downloaded and installed chromedriver (117.0.5938.88) and watir (6.19.1)
In IRB tried to create a watir instance
watir errors with: `undefined method` chrome' for Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities:Class`

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade to Watir 7 or downgrade your Selenium version. Selenium changed the methods it allows. Watir 7 is compatible, Watir 6 is not.

Comment: Thank you, that make sense. We unfortunately have a gem "Taza" which is not letting us upgrade to 7. This gets us closer to a solution though, thank you

Comment: oh wow, yes, that's an old gem. Actually, you can create a Selenium driver with the correct syntax for Selenium 4, and then just `browser = Watir::Browser.new(driver)` I'm not entirely sure how it works with Taza.